# ¿Como agregar el simbolo % al grafico

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy haciendo un grafico on matplotlib y quiero agregar el % al lado de cada valor pero no se como agregarlo, ¿Como lo podria agregar?

CODIGO:

````
bars = plt.bar(BeneficiosEconomicosNombres, height=BeneficiosEconomicosPorcentajes, width=.4)

for bar in bars:

    yval = bar.get_height()

    plt.text(bar.get_x() + .1, yval + 1, yval)

plt.ylim([0,100])

plt.title("BENEFICIOS ECONOMICOS")

plt.ylabel('Porcentajes')

plt.xlabel('Nombres Beneficios')

plt.show()```
````

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Usa str.format() para agregar el símbolo de porcentaje junto con el valor: plt.text(bar.get_x() + .1, yval + 1, "{:.0f}%".format(yval))